# How to add an input next to select in x-editable popup

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I'm using bootstrap x-editable to let users enter values. Here is my code:

```
    var supportSecondaryOptions = [
    { value: 'A', text: 'Prorated based on direct hours' },
    { value: 'B', text: 'Prorated based on client team HC' },
    { value: 'C', text: 'Explicitly defined percentage' }
    ];

 $("a[id^=secondaryoption_][id!='secondaryoption_{departmentid}']").editable({
        source: supportSecondaryOptions,
        onblur: 'submit',
        success: function (response, newValue) {
            $(this).attr("data-value", newValue);
        }
    });
```

This basically displays a popup with a select element that the user chooses. Now I`m being asked to add one other functionality. If the user selects a specific item (i.e. Explicitly defined percentage), an input element must appear next to the select element in the popup where the user must enter a ratio, i.e, "60/40". I tried to use the tpl option by entering the html for the input in there, but then I lose the select. So I tried to write the entire html into the tpl like this:

```
tpl: '<select class="form-control input-sm">' +
            '<option value="A">Prorated based on direct hours</option>' +
            '<option value="A">Prorated based on client team HC</option>' +
            '<option value="A">Explicitly defined percentage</option></select>' +
            ' <input style="width:50px;"></input>',
```

But now the input displays the value by default. I`m sure there is a better way to do this with x-editable. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

maybe hook an onchange event to the select?

```
$(".editable-input select").on('change', function () {
    $(this).after('<input style="width:50px;"></input>');
}
```